# Run a UI5 sample application from the documentation

Tags: sapui5, ui5-tooling

I am stuck on running a sample application.

Steps I tried so far:

1. Download the [sample](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.Table/sample/sap.m.sample.TableDnD).
2. Open in some editor (VScode)
3. Run `npm-install`
4. After referring some StackOverflow questions, I ran `npm install --global @ui5/cli`
5. Then start the server with `ui5 serve -o index.html`

I got the following error message:

> [npm translator] Failed to locate package.json for directory "F:\sap.m.sample.TableDnD"

What I found is there is no `package.json` file in this sample.

I tried a sample `package.json` from a running sample(Worklist app)from docs and made a change to name as of current project as:

```
{
  "name": "sap.m.sample.TableDnD", // It was Worklist in sample
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "SAP SE",
  "description": "UI5 Demo App - sap.m.sample.TableDnD(Standalone)", // It was Worklist in sample
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ui5 serve",
    "lint": "eslint webapp",
    "build": "rimraf dist && ui5 build --a"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@openui5/sap.ui.core": "^1.60",
    "@openui5/sap.ui.layout": "^1.60",
    "@openui5/sap.m": "^1.60",
    "@openui5/sap.f": "^1.60",
    "@openui5/themelib_sap_belize": "^1.60"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ui5/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  }
}
```

I tried running all the steps again then I got another error saying:

> No specification version defined for root project sap.m.sample.TableDnD

Any help or guiding links would be helpful. Looking for a solution who can just try the sample app in link and run.

Comment: Do ypu have a file `ui5.yaml`?

Comment: sorry I couldn't find that file

Comment: @Marc Could you just please download the sample and try running it? does this sample can be run or just use the files inside the sample in running apps?

Comment: Well you need to run a local webserver. @ui5/cli can do that for you if you have the proper config files (like ui5.yaml). If you are familiar with python it is literally a simple one liner to start a small server in the current directory. You can simply download the following sample app from SAP and replace the webapp content with your content: https://github.com/SAP-samples/openui5-sample-app

Comment: Idk about this but I am getting this error , `Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/table/sample/TableExampleUtils.js' from https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap/ui/table/sample/TableExampleUtils.js: script load error
    at HTMLScriptElement.b (ui5loader-dbg.js:1336)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run

```
ui5 init
```

once in your project directory. It will create the missing `ui5.yaml` and then `ui5 serve -o index.html` should work.

This is more deeply explained in [UI5 Tooling](https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/)

Comment: No, that is not enough, then it requires manifest.json, it is so weird that in 2023 it is still not fixed